# how to extract data from REST API to csv file using informatica cloud

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, rest, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

I have a REST API and i need to extract data from the API to a CSV file . Please let me know how we can do this in the Informatica cloud.
I am able to view data through postman.

Comment: youc an use java transformations to get/post. its little difficult but i can see this is one way to call rest api.

Comment: Is there a direct way like rest V2 connector?

Comment: i know how to do it in powercenter. But not in cloud version. i used http transformation.

Comment: can you check this video out - https://video.informatica.com/detail/videos/cloud-integration/video/5171093516001/using-rest-web-services-in-the-cloud